# problemas con variables factor en una regresion lineal en r

Tags: r, regresión-lineal, tidyverse

Hola estimados tengo el siguiente problema. Corro la regresion que esta abajo

```
modelo_1 <- lm(ln_p  ~ d25 + ht11  +  d9 +  factor(agua_red)-1 +  factor(d8_4)-1 +
                 cloacas_red + factor(calefaccion)-1 + factor(vivienda_casa)-1 + factor(vivienda_depto)-1 + factor(calidad_material)-1 +
                 + factor(propietario)-1 , 
               data = reg_hed)
```

y cuando veo los resultados me encuentro con lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como no me idientifica que la variable es factor(agua_red) -1 y me genera un probema en los indicadorores.

Agluien le paso como lo solucionaron?

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ahi encontre el error. Uno de los -1 me estaba sacando al intecepto de la ecucación.

eso resolvio el problema